# Asked for a regular expression, starting from the latest match?

Tags: javascript, c#

```
<a title="Fruit" href="cate1.html" data-type="cate" />
<a title="apple" href="article1.html" data-type="article" />
<a title="orange" href="article2.html" data-type="article" />
<a title="Vegetable" href="cate2.html" data-type="cate" />
<a title="cabbage" href="article3.html" data-type="article" />
```

I want match apple,orange,cabbage.

Using `<a title="(.+?)" href=".+?.html" data-type="article" />` gives me Fruit,orange,Vegetable.

What I can do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags - generally it's a bad idea to parse html with regex

Comment: It doesn't give you Fruit, orange, Vegetable. It does give you *exactly* what you want (apple,orange,cabbage), what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/tL6eC4/1

```
title="([a-z]+)"
```

This match what you want, they are in lower case.